# How to set Highcharts chart maximum yAxis value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been trying for two days to find a way to set the **maximum value** of the yAxis on Highcharts.

I got a percentage **column graphic**, but the highest value in the series is 60, so it adjusts the axis to **top at 70**, I found a way to **choose the start point**, but no way to **choose the end point**.

What I really need is to set the **yAxis from 0 to 100**, so the data will be more accurately viewed as percentage

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Try this:

```
yAxis: {min: 0, max: 100}
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbbGY/2909/) example

Comment: how do you change it dynamically in an existing graph ?

Comment: @Asaf pass the value of min and max dynamically then method above is static .

Comment: `min` and `max` are deprecated since Highcharts 2.2 http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min

Comment: @Oleg that is maxZoom you are reading. min and max are very much ok.

Comment: How can i control the overflow of the data if they exceed the scale? For example I want to add an arrow icon at the top of the bar

Comment: how can I set min, max for yAxis base on min, max of series data?

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively one can use the [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.setExtremes) method also,

```
yAxis.setExtremes(0, 100);
```

Or if only one value is needed to be set, just leave other as null

```
yAxis.setExtremes(null, 100);
```

Comment: This helped my situation, i.e. set the minimum and maximum of the axes after render time.

Answer (score 5):

Taking help from above answer link mentioned in the above answer sets the max value with option

```
yAxis: { max: 100 },
```

On similar line min value can be set.So if you want to set min-max value then

```
yAxis: {
   min: 0,     
   max: 100
},
```

If you are using HighRoller php library for integration if Highchart graphs then you just need to set the option

```
$series->yAxis->min=0;
$series->yAxis->max=100;
```

Comment: I have a chart with max values of 13417. So I want to show max 15000. But the chart shows max of 20000. If I put `max: 10000 `it shows  max 10000 but other values between 10-15000 always shows 20000. What am I doing wrong? Here is a demo [link](https://jsfiddle.net/asle/yhkrcque/14/)

Comment: @Asle I think you maybe found fix to your problem, but setting the tick interval will indeed fix it: https://jsfiddle.net/yhkrcque/24/

Comment: Yes @MiChAeLoKGB, it was the tick intervall that did the trick!