# Highcharts, make the yAxis start at zero

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I suppose this should be a no brainer for some, but I couldn't find it in those awful auto generated documentation

Comment: Its already documented at  http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#yAxis--min. If you didn't try or can't find. It does not mean its awful.

Comment: @HardikMishra, the given url seems to be broken. correct : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should add in your yAxis property in chart object `min : 0`
It's simillar question to: [How to set Highcharts chart maximum yAxis value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847244/how-to-set-highcharts-chart-maximum-yaxis-value?rq=1)

Comment: Note that `min` may not be strictly obeyed. In [this example](https://jsbin.com/fomoket/edit?js,output), I've set `min` to -1 but the yAxis goes down to -10.