# How to set a Maximum yAxis range for HighChart graph?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Below is a bar graph where the green bars never go over 100 and the red bars never go below -100.

However in the graph's yAxis you can see `-150%`.

I found [this fix here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847244/how-to-set-highcharts-chart-maximum-yaxis-value), however it did not work. `yAxis: {min: 0, max: 100}`

Is there another way to accomplish this?

[image]

Here is the area where I add those bar graphs

```
function addSentimentSeries(name, data) {
    var index = findTheIndex(name);

    var color = name === 'Positive sentiment' ? '#009900' : '#FF0000';

    if (index) {
        chart.series[index].update({
            showInLegend: false,
            yAxis: 2,
            type: 'column',
            name: name,
            color: color,
            data: data,
            dataGrouping: { enabled: false }
        }, true);
    } else {
        chart.addSeries({
            showInLegend: false,
            yAxis: 2,
            type: 'column',
            name: name,
            color: color,
            data: data,
            dataGrouping: { enabled: false }
        }, true);
    }

    chart.hideLoading();
    chart.redraw();
}
```

---

This is the 'fix' I implemented from the answer I found above, it did not do anything, my bar graphs still display -150%

```
vm.config.yAxis.push({
    height: '30%',
    top: '70%',
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    title: {
       text: 'Sentiment',
       style: { color: '#BFBFBF' }
    },
    yAxis: { min: 0, max: 100 },
    offset: 0,
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.value + '%';
        },
        style: { color: '#BFBFBF' }
    },
    opposite: false
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "it did not work" about the fix you found?

Comment: @HalvorStrand just added more details about the fix

Comment: Thanks. Type-o? The `min` and `max` should be directly in the root, not inside a `yAxis` attribute.

Comment: Where in the root? Btw my chart has multiple graphs and 3 yAxis.

Comment: I'm thinking instead of `yAxis: { min: 0, max: 100 },` it should be `min: 0, max: 100,`, if I'm understanding the setup correctly.

Comment: And I guess in your case it would be `min: -100, max: 100,` since that is what you've described as the range.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying this `chart.series[negIndex].yAxis.min = -100;` however the result is still the screenshot I posted above :'(

Comment: It should be more like `chart.yAxis[0].min = -100`.

Comment: Have you tried to set [minPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.minPadding) / [maxPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.maxPadding) parameters as 0 ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan AH THAT WAS IT THANKS! Want to post the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the [minPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.minPadding) and [maxPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.maxPadding) parameters as 0, then you reduce the spacing on a axis.

```
yAxis: {
   minPadding: 0,
   maxPadding: 0
}
```